# Twitter Share inside Frame

Tags: html

I try to make a iframe modal with a twitter share src.

```
<iframe src="https://twitter.com/share" class="tweetFrame"></iframe>
```

This isn't working, the page will stay blank. How can I bypass the Twitter system so it displays the twitter page inside the iframe?

Answer (score 1):

That twitter resource sends an

```
X-Frame-Options:    SAMEORIGIN
```

response header, telling the browser that it should not be displayed inside any kind of (i)frame on 3rd party sites.

So in short: You can’t achieve that, because twitter doesn’t allow it.

Comment: That sucks. Thanks for your answer!